# Retrieving multiple rows from stored procedures

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008

My stored procedure `proc_search` returns only the name on execution and I have been using the following code in ASP.NET to display the value...

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("proc_search", con);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@branch", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = branchidtext.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Acct", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = accountidtext.Text;

SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while (reader.Read())
{
    nametext.Text = reader[0].ToString();
}
```

If I have a procedure which returns multiple columns and multiple rows like Name, Address, Age... How do I display it in the text boxes? Please help.

Comment: If you need to display **multiple rows**, then static textboxes aren't well suited. Look into things like `ListView`, or `GridView`, to show several rows of data at once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know exact order of data you can say

```
 while (reader.Read())
    {
    nametext.Text = reader[0].ToString();
    agetext.Text = reader[1].ToString();
    addresstext.Text = reader[2].ToString();
}
```

etc... If you don't know the ordering than say

```
 while (reader.Read())
    {
    nametext.Text = reader["Name"].ToString();
    agetext.Text = reader["Age"].ToString();
    addresstext.Text = reader["Address"].ToString();
}
```

Comment: Yes. [0], [1] are column numbers and ["Name"], ["Age"] are column names.

Comment: Now i am using                                                    while (reader.Read())
        {
            nametext.Text = reader[0].ToString();
            branchtext.Text = reader[1].ToString();
        } to get multiple values from procedure.....IF the procedures gets no records then it gives a message "No records found". While using this i am getting an error in asp. 'Index was outside the bounds of the array.'

Answer (score 0):

Use this kind of method. This will retun dataset having multiple rows and cols

```
 public DataSet GetDataSet()
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(con);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "proc_search";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        da.SelectCommand = cmd;
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        conn.Open();
        da.Fill(ds);
        conn.Close();

        return ds;
    }
```